# for Kubuntu: how to get a working pdftotext

Tags: kubuntu

I am running Kubuntu 20.04. Therein is installed pdftotext based on poppler-utils, version 0.86.1-0ubuntu1.

This pdftotext does not work. I have tried very many different pdf files. It gives no output, no error message.

On my other computer with KNOPPIX,  pdftotext does work.

In Internet there are articles about working pdftotext version 0.90.

How can I get a working version of pdftotext, and one normal, i.e.  non-poppler version, and a newer one as I have.

My aptitude, apt-get, apt-file, dpkg all are of no help.

Regards
antondhidh

Comment: Make sure the PDF file actually has text and not only images of text. For images of text you need to do OCR. A pretty quick way to find out is to try to select text while viewing it. If you cannot select a single word ... then there is no text.

Comment: Thank you for your answere by Eduardo Trapani. You are right, that is indeed a cause for problems. My  important .pdf files are invoices I got as attachments to emails, and the sender had presumingly scanned-in a printed incoice.

Comment: When scanning in e.g. via a multi-purpose printer, the result will always be an image of text.

Comment: Since this is the common way to transfer invoices etc. via email, these /.pdf could never be convert by pdftotext, but only by ocr. - But no one ocr tool is contained in Kubuntu. -- All very disappointing. -- I prefere to use a dektop like KDE 3.  -- What I read about Ubuntu 22.xx is no hope. -- And KNOPPIX is no more as good as many years ago. -- I have to give up, I close this my question, thank you all. Regards. antondhidh